# SOAP UI how to define any date - expression

Tags: datetime, expression, soapui

How can I easily define any date that I put in the request?
I put today's date as

```
<BeginDate>${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())}</BeginDate
```

and I would also like to use TODAY + 1 YEAR or some other value.
Or in EndDate put BeginDate + 1 year (30 days) ect

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a Groovy script step to calculate it, and store it in a property like this:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def oneYear
use(TimeCategory) {
    oneYear = (new Date() + 1.year).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    log.info oneYear
}

testCase.setPropertyValue("OneYearFromNow", oneYear)
```

Then use the property value in the request like this:

```
<BeginDate>${#TestCase#OneYearFromNow}</<BeginDate>
```

Comment: You stored it in `testCase.testSuite.project`, but you are reading it from `#TestCase#`?